# css - horizontal menu - background-color

Tags: css

I have a horizontal menu. I want to have a border around the menu (not the entire-row, only the space menu is covering). When I put border on ul, it covers the entire row, when I put border on li, it has border between menu items as well.

```
<ul id="menu" style = "text-align:left;">  

                    <li>...anchor stuff...
                    </li><li>...anchor stuff...
                    </li><li>...anchor stuff...
                    </li><li>...anchor stuff...
                    </li><li>...anchor stuff...</li>
                </ul>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
ul#menu
{
    padding: 0 0 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 0;
    text-align: right;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

ul#menu li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}


ul#menu li a
{
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin-right:20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand your code? Why do you set text-align:left on the #menu element inline, and text-align:right on the same element in the CSS?

Comment: Also, why have you set position:relative on the #menu element? There doesn't seem to be a need for that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kill `display: inline` on the list items and float them left instead. Float the container as well, which will ensure that it's only as wiide as its contents. Finally, set `overflow: hidden` on the ul.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `ul` with `display:inline-block`. It'll cause `ul` to take only space necessary to display its contents, not 100% of it.

[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/7tsLV/1/)

Comment: I believe inline-block is not supported in IE6/7. If so, can it be used as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` on the `ul` and add the border to the `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need IE6 compatibility:

```
#menu li {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00;
    }
```

You might be able to use `li:first-child` (I can't remember, and don't have a copy of IE6 to test with) to apply:

```
#menu li:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    }
```

But you'll likely have to add either a `class`-name, or `id`, to the first and last `li` elements to give them the appropriate `border-left` and `border-right`.